# Is there a good way to save formatting information in a plain text document so that Microsoft Word understands it?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, plaintext

I want to export some data from a database. I can do so in plain text. However, I would like to add formatting tags. Afterwards I want to be able to open the files in Microsoft Word.

Of course, I could use html-formatting and save the file as a .docx file. I was wondering though, if there is a better way to do this.

I aim at a few simple formatting types: bold, italics, font size change and font change.

Comment: Word understands lots of formats. HTML sprung to mind even before reading your whole question, but there's also RTF. What kind of things are you trying to do?

Comment: @MrLister: I updated my question. Just a few basic ones.

Comment: I think HTML and RTF are your best bets. Most other formats Word recognises aren't plain text, so those are out.

Comment: RTF seems a bit verbose. I saved a file from word to rtf and it had a lot of code/tags in there. Or is there a way to strip a lot of the code?

Comment: Heh, if you save a Word file as HTML you get the same bloating. AFAIK the simplest RTF starts with `{rtf1` on a line by itself and ends with `}`, and everything in between is content. See http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html But I don't know if there's a cleanup tool for existing RTF documents if that's what you mean.

Comment: Funny thing: if I make a rtf file word asks for file conversion. However, when I do the same with the file in the tutorial you provided, word opens it without a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, when I do try to convert, I don't get the formatting, but the same result as if I would open the rtf in notepad...

Comment: I'm not really an RTF guru, sorry. That's why I didn't post an answer. But maybe this problem should be a question of its own. If you do that, you can tag it with `rtf` and attract some real experts.